# onClick with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, html, buttonclick

how can i play a sound with onClick and open a new html site in the existing window?
Sometimes it plays the sound, and sometimes the new site open.

Thanks for your help!

```
<div class="lowersitebuttons">
<button class="login" onClick="PlaySound(button1); window.location.href = '/Users/Mac/Dropbox/Sites/lcars1.html'">LOGIN</button>
<button class="cancel" onClick="PlaySound(button2)">CANCEL</button> 
</div>


    // JavaScript Document
    var button = new Audio();
    button1.src = "/Users/Mac/Dropbox/login/Computersounds/lcars.mp3";
    function PlaySound(button1) {
        button1.play();
    }

    button2.src = "/Users/Mac/Dropbox/login/Computersounds/alert23.mp3";
    function PlaySound(button2) {
        button2.play();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack! I would highly recommend against inline Javascript. Instead, go and have a look at [event binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) through Javascript.

Comment: Why not define a new function that calls all the other necessary functions? And then you can call that one function from onClick.

Answer (score 3):

When the new URL is loaded your sound will stop playing. Instead you may want to wait until your sound was played to finish and load the new URL after that. To do so you can use the `onend` event of an Audio object.

```
button1.play();
button1.onend = function()
{
    window.location.href = "/Users/Mac/Dropbox/Sites/lcars1.html";
}
```